# Send image(jpg) via HttpPost from Android to Servlet(WebServer)

Tags: android, image, servlets, send, http-post

I have an image sitting on my SDcard (of type jpg) and I am trying to send the image via HttpPost to my servlet running on Apache Tomcat 7.0

So far I have google-ing the way to do this but I can't seem to find the perfect way.

Do any of you might have some suggestion or solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance,
Sammy Stevan Djap

Answer (score 1):

[HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) is the class to use and  there's a [tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=288) for it. See the section *Using HTTP client*, right after the pictures.

**UPDATE**
What follows is commentary on the tutorial example from [Developerlife.com](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=288).  A good thing about that example is that it demonstrates how to send various types of data by encoding one type into another.  One can send any of the types used in that chain of data conversions, by starting at the point in the chain that matches the type of data to be sent:

*Strings* are put in a *Hashtable* which is written to an *ObjectOutputStream* which is backed by a *ByteArrayOutputStream* that gets converted into a ByteArray that is in turn converted into a ByteArrayEntity for transmission.

To send just a *ByteArray*, skip all the steps that occur before the data becomes a *ByteArray*. Jump in at line 26 where a *ByteArray* is created with `toByteArray().`

For sending other types do the following(as per the example):
Line 26: *ByteArray*, just use it to make a *ByteArrayEntity*
Line 26: *ByteArrayOutputStream*, convert it to a *ByteArray*
Line 24: *ObjectOutputStreams*: create them on  *ByteArrayOutputStreams*
Line 25: *Objects*: Write *Strings*, *Hashtables*, etc to an *ObjectOutputStream*.

```
 1 /** this method is called in a non-"edt" thread */
 2 private void _doInBackgroundPost() {
 3   Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "background task - start");
 4 
 5 
 6   Hashtable<String, String> map = new Hashtable();
 7   map.put("uid", uid);
 8   map.put("pwd", pwd);
 9 
10   try {
11     HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
12 
13     // set params for connection...
14     HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(params, false);
15     HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, NetworkConnectionTimeout_ms);
16     HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, NetworkConnectionTimeout_ms);
17     DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
18 
19     // create post method
20     HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(LoginServiceUri);
21 
22     // create request entity
23     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
24     ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
25     oos.writeObject(map);
26     ByteArrayEntity req_entity = new ByteArrayEntity(baos.toByteArray());
27     req_entity.setContentType(MIMETypeConstantsIF.BINARY_TYPE);
28
```

Comment: well, I have seen this tutorial before, but it shows the way to send character strings. I am not sure how to send a byte[] with the same method

Comment: No they send a ByteArrayEntity made from a ByteArray.  The ByteArray just so happens to have been created from *Strings* about 6 conversions prior.  [Strings like "pwd" in Java are Objects](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), a lot more complex than  C-style character strings, which  are quite close to *ByteArray.* I updated the answer, hopefully with a clearer explanation of how ByteArray is sent.

Comment: Is it also useful when making LOGIN and LOGOUT logic with required certain social media like Facebook for example?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in a little bit cleaner way but with asp.net 'web form'. I am sure someone can easily do a makeover of that in servlet. You can find my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085629/android-image-upload-problem/5727217#5727217).

cheers

Fahar