# Android image upload problem on server side

Tags: android, image

I am developing an application to upload an image from Android mobile to the web server.
On the android side, I am using the code as mentioned in the link here 
[Android file uploader with server-side php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204476/android-file-uploader-with-server-side-php)

On the server side, when I try to receive the file, it fails in move_uploaded_file function. The apache server side php code is

$target_path="uploads/";

$target_path=$target_path.basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],$target_path)) {

echo "OK";

}else{

echo "FAIL";
}

The problem is that the file is not getting copied in the uploads folder. Can anyone please help?

Rgds,
Sapan

Comment: check error_log and access_log. May be permission issue of uploads folder.

Comment: nothing in error log and access log. Also checked for the permissions of the folder. It is not read only

Comment: May also be permissions on the /tmp directory (or wherever PHP is configured to write uploads). Echoing out $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] may shed some light. Personally I'd knock together an HTML test harness to be 100% sure it isn't the client.

Comment: I echoed the $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] and it displays icon.png which is the file I am trying to upload...I have no knowledge on php and html..so dont know how to write the html test

Comment: Exact duplicate as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085629/android-image-upload-problem