# How to send data from Android application to Java Server(Apache tomcat)?

Tags: java, android, json, sockets

I am going to start an application, that requires that data should be passed from Android to Java Server. This data can be in one of the 2 forms

1. Raw text data i.e. in form of Text or Json format and
2. Bitmap form data like images or Serialized Objects.

Some suggested me to use Json Objects OR Java Socket API.

How do I use them to send data to server with requests?

Comment: i think this link has a solution for you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393112/uploading-image-to-apache-tomcat-server-with-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this answer:
It is about send image to web server

go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047731/send-imagejpg-via-httppost-from-android-to-servletwebserver).

Comment: Is it also useful when making LOGIN and LOGOUT logic with required certain social media like Facebook for example?